# Mysql login without password in terminal

Tags: passwords, mysql, root, ubuntu-20.04

I have an Ubuntu 20 server with Mysql installation. I am sure the root user have a password set. But if I run command `mysql -u root` it does not require password and run mysql with all privileges. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

As I found out the login from terminal as root user password is not used at all. In Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later), the root user is authenticated by the auth_socket plugin by default. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: If and when you have conflicts with other packages on your system (which has happened to me 100% of the time), the built in MariaDB server packages provided by your distro will not.

Comment: No I have a problem with PhpMyAdmin installation and it is like a nightmare.